# What is the semantic difference between the Java fonts Monospaced and DialogInput?

Tags: java, fonts

I can not find the place where the Java documentation explains it. The API documentation does not do it:

- [Monospaced](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#MONOSPACED)
- [DialogInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#DIALOG_INPUT)

Comment: what you mean by semantic difference?

Comment: Fonts don't have semantics. Not a real question.

Comment: @ejp Monospaced and DialogInput are logical font names and therefor have of course a semantic meaning, because they are meant to be used in specific use cases. If you are to clumsy to understand the question ask so that someone can explains it to you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking, but font references are usually identified by where they are used. For example:

- Monospace fonts are normally used for text where the columns should align - e.g. for code.
- I am not familiar with `AWT`, but I would assume that `DialogInput` is the default font to use in dialog input text fields. I would expect that to match what native applications use for a consistent visual result.

There is no documented difference because each font reference has its own target uses. The actual font may or may not be different, depending on the underlying configuration.

What you use in your code is left at your own discretion, especially when there is a conceptual overlap or conflict. For example, you should probably use a monospace font for a textbox where a user is expected to submit code, rather than the default dialog input font.

P.S.: BTW it's amazing how many applications ask users to write code (e.g. CSS) in text boxes without a monospace font. Why should I have to paste code back and forth to an editor for no reason? Is that really so hard to get right?

Comment: I was wondering, if DialogInput is necessarily a mono space font. A terminal program for example is a dialog and input. But would DialogInput be the right font?

Comment: @ceving: I would expect `DialogInput` to be a variable width form by default, because that is generally more presentable. If your *specific* dialog is a terminal, however, you would of course have to explicitly use a monospace font...

Comment: Do you know where the meaning of Monospaced and DialogInput is specified in the Java documentation?

Comment: BTW did you vote for closing this question so that nobody else but you can answer it?

Comment: @ceiving: I voted for closing it (and I was not the only one) because the only way to answer it was to take a shot in the dark... To be honest I am still not certain what the exact problem is - to me the use of those constants seems self-evident...

Comment: @ceiving: I am not sure you will find anything further about those fonts. May I suggest downloading the JDK sources and searching for those constants? Seeing how they are used and what their default values are might give you the information that you are looking for.